# Build argument with Dockerfile CMD

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile, environment-variables

In my Dockerfile cmd command is like this,

```
CMD ["java", "-javaagent:dd-java-agent.jar", "-Ddd.env=my_env", "-Ddd.agent.host=172.17.0.2", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I want to make this `dd.agent.host` and `dd.env` values to be dynamic when building the images or run the containers.

Can anyone please let me know a way to do this without changing to `CMD ["sh", "-c", "java..."]` format.

When I changed to `CMD ["sh", "-c", "java..."]` and used ARG and ENV to do this and with that changes log4j2.xml file environment variables (`${env:service-host}`) not getting the value. Any idea on this?

Comment: The ability to substitude an environment variable name to it's value is of shell or bash. So you can not do it without shell or bash as docker does not wrap the CMD in shell unless you specified it. Can you share your full `sh -c` CMD.

Comment: You don't need to spell out `sh -c`; specifying `CMD ... -Ddd.env=${DD_ENV}` should be enough.  But as @TruongHua indicates you do need a shell in some form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. I have fixed this without setting datadog values in CMD command and pass it in the docker run command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research on this problem I found that without setting -Ddd.agent.host and -Ddd.env in the CMD we can pass it in the docker run command as a environment variables. I have added following to the docker run command.

```
-e DD_AGENT_HOST=172.17.0.2 -e DD_ENV=my_env
```